# MongoDB - searching query for deeply nested arrays only

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

That's a piece of my database:

[my database is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNdAY.png)

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Barber',
    required: true,
  },
  month: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  availability: [{
    day: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    hours: [{
      hour: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      status: String,
      clientName: String,
      serviceType: String,
    }],
  }],
});
```

I'm trying to create a query that will allow me to find out if at a given day, a given hour is already in the database (let's say: find if at day 8, hour 800 is already taken).

I tried the following expression:

```
Availability.find(
      { $and: [{ 'availability.hours.hour': '800' }, { 'availability.day': 8 }] },
 );
```

...but it gives me true instead of false, as both day 8 exists and hour 800 exists, BUT what I want to find out is if hour 800 exists within day 8.

Do you guys have any hints?

Comment: it will be better if you gave a sample data in code format, but you can try out $elemMatch https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: If the `hour` type is `Number` then you can remove that single quotes (`'800'`), other than that your query looks correct. Also, please output the result and check

Comment: Also, can you tell how you are checking its a true or false

Comment: This seems to works fine:

```Availability.find({ availability: { $elemMatch: { day: 8, 'hours.hour': 1000 } } });```